# How can I turn a list of words in a text file into a regex to filter out?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to filter out some text for certain keywords that are found in a text file. I was thinking about just parsing the file line by line, take each word and then merge them together with a pipe "|" then using that string inside re.sub.

Any better more efficient ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you add an example? How big of a file? How many keywords?

Comment: A file with 80 or so lines. One word per line.

Comment: is efficiency really that important? Will you use the script over and over again, on relatively large (millions?) of lines?

Comment: Why not use a simple `str.index()` in a `for` loop instead of regex? Unless you're filtering hundreds of thousands of lines on a regular basis, searching a string for 80 or so keywords is not going to take a substantial amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this without regexp?

```
import string
keyset = set(open('keywords.txt').read().splitlines())
for lineno,line in  enumerate(open('textfile.txt')):
    result = [kw
              for kw in keyset
              for w in line.split()
              if kw in w and w.strip(string.punctuation) == kw]
    if result:
        print "%5s (%s): %s" % (lineno,', '.join(result), line),
```

Comment: Why use `filter` since you're using a generator expression anyway?

Comment: I removed filter and considered punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
import re

with file('keywords.txt', 'r') as k:
    kwords = sorted(k.read().strip().split(), lambda x: (len(x), x))
searchstring = r'\s?\b(' + '|'.join(kwords) + r')\b'
with file('textfile.txt', 'r') as t:
    text = t.read()
newtext, _ = re.subn(searchstring, '', text).lstrip()
```